# decoding hexdecimals from URLs

Tags: url, unicode, hex

a lot of sites like google and wikipedia encode non-english characters in hex with a leading '%' sign.
I looked for a tool that I could pipe URLs into it and, when such %AA strings are met, will translate these signs back to utf so that I can read them.

as I couldn't find one, I wrote it myself in c and I'd like to share it with you, maybe you'll find it useful:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
   {
        char c;
        unsigned int i;
        while (!feof(stdin))
        {
                if (0==fread(&c,1,1,stdin)) break;
                if (c!='%') putchar(c);
                else
                {
                        if (scanf("%X",&i)==1) putchar(i);
                        else putchar('%');
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

usage example:

> # echo
>   "http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99"
>   | ./dumpHex

results:

```
http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/עמוד_ראשי
```

Comment: Depending on what language and framework you're using, such utilities are common: [Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rcp.jcl.desktop.javadoc/doc/java/net/URLDecoder.html), [Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VC++:

```
string dec = URLDecoder::decode(url)
```

PHP:

```
$d = urldecode($u)
```

Java:

```
String dec = URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8");
```

etc...

Comment: Your question presents a string that that is a specific case of [URL Encoding](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), that is, the conversion of characters that are not safe for use in a URL into an octect in the form of `"%xx"' where "`x`" is a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: @akiva_eshbal, Strictly speaking, if you want to convert hexadecimal octects into characters and each octect is differentiated from the non-encoded content by a preceding `'%'`, you're looking at either URL encoding or an adaptation of it.

Comment: @akiva_eshbal, the string can however consist of anything, and any of the above examples will decode any `"%xx"` tokens in them. E.g. `"עמוד_ראשי" == URLDecoder::decode("%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99")`.